# $X$- amount of experiments conducted until certain number of coloured balls is pulled out. Write an distribution of $X$

Tags: probability

Given that in the box there are $4$ white and $4$ black marbles and that $4$ marbles are randomly selected and then put back into the box, what is the distribution $X$ if the experiment is conducted until $2$ white and $2$ black marbles are selected. $X$ describes an amount of experiments conducted. I have no idea how to describe $X$, because if the marbles are put back, each time a probability that $2$ black and $2$ white marbles will be pulled out stays the same. If total amount of distinct selections is $2^4$ and you can select two marbles of each colour in $6$ ways, then the probability that you will select two marbles of each colour is $\frac{6}{16}=\frac{3}{8}$. But I don't know how to proceed and describe $X$ given that $1,2,3,...$ is an amount of experiments.

Comment: Is $X$ the number of experiments needed to come to the first time that the experiment "succeeds" in the sense that $2$ black and $2$ white marbles are selected? If so then $X$ has [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and it is up to you to find the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(X=n)=\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)^{n-1}\frac{3}{8}$$ because you succeed on the $n$th trial if and only if you fail on the first $n-1$ trials and succeed on the $n$th. The trials are independent. You have correctly identified the chance of succeeding on each trial as $\frac{3}{8}$.

Note that $1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$ and so it is easy to check that the probabilities for $n=1,2,3\dots$ add up to 1.